# Angular adding extra logic to 404 handling on non angular routes

Tags: angularjs, redirect, amazon-s3

I have an angular site hosted in S3, and I have a 404 route set up (I use hash), if someone for example does

```
mysite/#/gibberish
```

goes to

```
mysite/#/404
```

and on the s3 bucket we have a redirect rule in place for

```
mysite/gibberish
```

goes to

```
mysite/404.html
```

all is well

Now I just want to add an extra logic on top that if someone types in

mysite/customerid

which is a 404 to somehow redirect this to an angular controller so I can send this request to right page.

So somehow in my redirect in S3 rule add a reg exp for some incoming request and rather than serve 404.html send it i.e. mysite/#/handlethis

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the router of your choice, you could do something like the following (which is what we've done (well, not precisely *this*, but close)):

#### ui-router

```
app.config(function ($urlRouterProvider) {
  var regx = /\/#\//; // match against /#/

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function ($state, $location) {
    if (!regx.test($location.path()) { // if no match
      $state.go('customHandlingState', /** params **/, /** configuration **/ }); 
      // Transition to your custom handler state, with optional params/config. 
    }
  });
});
```

You could pair this up with custom `stateChange[Start|Stop|Error|Success]` handlers in the `run` block of your app to customise it to your liking.

*I would supply an example of how to do this with ngRoute, but I gave up on ngRoute two years ago and haven't looked back since. As such I have no suggestion to give, nor was I able to find a solution to the problem you present.*

I would **strongly** suggest you scrap the S3 portion of this recipe as it will make your life a lot easier when it comes to client side routing (speaking from personal experience here, *it's my opinion on the matter - not fact*) and handle your `404's`/`500's` on the client with custom state handlers.

If need be you could hook into some logging service and store some data whenever a client/person ends up in an erroneous state.

> I suppose my 'counter question' is; What do **you** gain from using S3 redirect rules? So as to get a better understanding for the needs and goals here.

---

Some reference material to go along:

- [ui-router#$state.go](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state#methods_go)
- [ui-router#$urlRouterProvider.otherwise](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#otherwise-for-invalid-routes)

Comment: The above will just let me handle the 404's, if the url is like mysite.com/#/some404...but if a user does mysite.com/some404 it's a 404 on the server and doesn't even get to the angular side of things i.e. just get Cannot GET /qweqwe

Comment: Which is why I suggested you scrap the 404 handling on the server and just send the request on its merry way to the clientside application, regardless of the lack of `/#/` in the URL. **If that is not an option**, its like you said; You need to setup an equivalent re-route of what I suggested on S3 to send the request to `mysite/#/` and then let the clientside application pick up from there. In which case you can safely disregard from the answers given to you so far as they are all related to clientside routing (mine included). Or am I misreading the situation?

Comment: Yeah I see what you mean I think I will scrap my current s3 redirect rule to /404.html to go instead to /#/incorrectpath. then use the ng route otherwise to use regex or something to look at the path and if it matches certain criteria perform an action otherwise go to /#/404.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to persuade you into doing so. *Welcome to the SPA, have a towel! : )*

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using routeParams
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams

the route would look like this:
/mysite/:cid

then access the id with the controller:
$routeParams.cid

I hope this could help

Comment: but I use /#/ in my url not html 5 turned, so it wouldn't even get to my angular code by default

Answer (score 0):

You can manually configure your server to always serve your index.html(your main html file which includes reference to angular script) on all incoming http requests. Client routing will be handled by Angular

Comment: and how could index.html then tell about the actual previous request to see what id was in the url to do certain logic